# Retrieve firebase realtime database when branch head is a UUID

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I started with firebase some months back and I only stored data. It was an experiment project so I changed the realtime database rules as "anyone can read or write to the database."
In order to make the entries unique I used `let uuid = UUID()`. Now as I got time to continue the experiment I am having this issue when I ant to retrieve the values. Here is the structure:

[image]
The number 3759... is the head and it is a `UUID`. To read the data I've added this code:

```
Database
    .database()
    .reference()
    .child("items")
    .queryOrderedByKey()
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }
        let question = dict["question"] as? String
        print(dict, question ?? "no value")
    })
```

Here I get all the JSON structure in `dict` but `nil` in `question`. Now I understand I have to add a child after `.child("items")` but how can I do that as the head nodes are all `UUID`.

Comment: What does `.child("items")` point to? Also note that it's easier to help if you share the JSON as text, instead of a screenshot. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started studying Firebase two days ago, and I worked on the same problem some 18 hours ago.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    var dataReference: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // getting a node from database //
        dataReference = Database.database().reference().child("items")

        // observing data changes //
        dataReference.observe(DataEventType.value) { (dataSnapshot) in
            if dataSnapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                for item in dataSnapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let uuid = item.key
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```